# Replacing a name column with an equivalent id value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I currently have a column in a table which contains employee_names. Since then I have created a table containing employee information and would like to replace the employee_names column with an employee_id column that corresponds to the values already in the table.

Seems like a fairly basic question but can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

EDIT: Adding table structure

```
Responsible_table:
category_name,
employee_name (Has duplicates)

Employee_table:
employee_id {PK},
employee_name,
employee_address,
etc.
```

Also if anyone can help with how to generate the employee table with a unique id for each employee_name in the Responsible_table that would be great

Comment: Please add your table structure to the question above. Use the `edit` button for that. This allows far better answers, since one does not have to write in general terms but can give a specific solution. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. First time posting to stack overflow. Let me know if there's any other information I can provide.

Comment: Your question is unclear, and your research suspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my approach:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2eb74

In that fiddle you can play around with the data, helps a lot to try things... First click the button "Build Schema" on the lower left, then try the "Run SQL" button on the right.

---

Here is the content of the fiddle above:

Setting up some test data:

```
CREATE TABLE responsible (
  category VARCHAR(100), 
  name VARCHAR(255)
);
INSERT INTO responsible VALUES
('teaching', 'First PersonA'),
('cleaning', 'Second PersonB'),
('watch', 'Third PersonC'),
('sleep', 'Fourth PersonD'),
('shopping', 'Third PersonC');

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  address VARCHAR(255), 
  PRIMARY KEY k_employee_id(id)
);
INSERT INTO employee VALUES
(NULL, 'First PersonA', 'some address'),
(NULL, 'Second PersonB', 'some address'),
(NULL, 'Some Person', 'some address'),
(NULL, 'Third PersonC', 'some address'),
(NULL, 'Other Person', 'some address'),
(NULL, 'Fourth PersonD', 'some address');
```

The actual conversion of the schemas:

```
ALTER TABLE responsible ADD COLUMN id INT;
UPDATE responsible r LEFT JOIN employee e ON (r.name=e.name) SET r.id=e.id;
ALTER TABLE responsible MODIFY COLUMN id INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE responsible ADD FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES employee(id) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE responsible DROP COLUMN name;
```

And a final test statement as proof of the above:

```
SELECT * FROM responsible;
```

You first add an `id` column to table `responsible` which is then filled by the following `UPDATE` statement joining the `employee` table. What is left is to modify the now filled `responsible.id` column as it makes sense and to drop column `responsible.name` column which is obsolete now.

Comment: Another awesome comment. Thanks heaps. I'll let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to:

1. create a new column `employee_id`
2. fill in the new column with data from the table employees
3. delete the old column `employee_name`

   ALTER TABLE Responsible_table ADD COLUMN employee_id INT;

   UPDATE Responsible_table rt INNER JOIN Employee_table et 
   ON rt.employee_name = et.employee_name 
   SET rt.employee_id = et.employee_id;

   ALTER TABLE Responsible_table DROP COLUMN employee_name;

**As for populating the table `Employee_table`:**

1. create the table
2. populate it

   CREATE TABLE Employee_table (
        employee_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
        employee_name VARCHAR(32),
        PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
   ) ENGINE=MyISAM;

   INSERT INTO Employee_table (employee_name) SELECT DISTINCT employee_name FROM Responsible_table;

Comment: Thanks for the awesome comment. Seems to be pretty much what I'm looking for. I'll give it a go when I get home and select you as my answer if it works.